# Convert hyperbola to Bézier curve for graphing orbital paths

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, bezier

I am writing a 2D simulator and game using the HTML canvas which involves orbital mechanics. One feature of the program is to take the position and velocity vector of a satellite at one point and return the semi-major axis, eccentricity, argument of periapsis, etc of a 2D orbit around one planet. When the eccentricity is less than one, I can easily graph the orbit as an ellipse using ctx.ellipse(). However, for eccentricities greater than one, the correct shape of the orbit is a hyperbola. At the moment, my program just draws nothing if the eccentricity is greater than one, but I would like it to graph the correct hyperbolic orbit. Since there is no built in "hyperbola" function, I need to convert my orbit into a Bézier curve. I am at a bit of a loss as to how to do this. The inputs would be the location of one focus, semi-major axis, eccentricity, and argument of periapsis (basically how far the orbit is rotated) and it should return the correct control points to graph a Bézier curve approximation of a hyperbola. It does not have to be exactly perfect, as long as it is a close enough fit. How can I approach this problem?

Comment: Sample a few points on your ellipse or hyperbola and create a catmull-rom spline. Each segment of the catmull-rom spine is a cubic Bezier curve.

Comment: Show your code and we might assist you in fixing it perhap.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In terms of conic sections, hyperbola are unfortunately the one class of curves that the Canvas *cannot* natively render, so you're stuck with approximating the curve you need. There are some options here:

1. Flatten your curve, by sampling the hyperbola at one or two points in the distance and *lots* of points near the extrema so that you can draw a simple polygon that *looks* like a curve.
2. Model the hyperbola with a single "best approximation" quadratic or cubic curve.
3. As @fang mentions: sample the curve at a few points and convert the Catmull-Rom spline through those points to Bezier form.
4. Combine approaches 1 and 2. using a single Bezier curve to approximate the part of the hyperbola that actually looks curved, and using straight lines for the parts that don't.
5. Combine approaches 1 and 3, using a Catmull-Rom spline for the curvy bit, and straight lines for the straight bits.

#### 1: Curve flattening

Curve flattening is basically trivial. Rotate your curve until it's axis-aligned, and then just compute `y` given `x` using the standard hyperbolic function, where `a` is half the distance between the extrema, and `b` is the semi-minor axis:

```
x²/a² - y²/b² = 1
x²/a² = 1 + y²/b² 
x²/a² - 1 = y²/b² 
b²(x²/a² - 1) = y²
b²(x²/a² - 1) = y²
± sqrt(b²(x²/a² - 1)) = y
```

plug in your values, iterate over `x` to get a sequence of `(x,y`) coordinates (remembering to generate more coordinates near the extrema), then turn those into a `moveTo()` for the first coordinate, followed by however many `lineTo()` calls you need for the rest. As long as your point density is high enough for the scale you're presenting, this should look fine:

```
function flattenHyperbola(a, b, inf=1000) {
  const points = [],
        a2 = a**2,
        b2 = b**2;

  let x, y, x2;

  for (x=inf; x>0.1; x/=2) {
    x2 = (a+x)**2;
    y = -Math.sqrt(b2*x2/a2 - b2);
    points.push({x: a+x, y});
  }

  points.push({x:a, y:0});

  for (x=0.1; x<inf; x*=2) {
    x2 = (a+x)*(a+x);
    y = Math.sqrt(b2*x2/a2 - b2);
    points.push({x:  a+x, y});
  }

  return points;
}
```

Let's plot the hyperbola in red and the approximation in blue:

[image: curve flattening using logarithmic intervals]

Of course the downside with this approach is that you will need to create a separate flattened curve for every scale the user may view your graphics at. Or, you need to generate a flattened curve with *lots and lots* of points, and then draw it by skipping over coordinates depending on how zoomed in/out things are.

#### 2: Bezier approximation

The parametric representation of a hyperbola is `f(t)=(a*sec(t), b*tan(t))` (or rather, that's the representation for the y-axis aligned hyperbola - we can get any other variant by applying the standard rotation transform). We can have a quick look at the Taylor series for these functions to see which order of Bezier curve we can use:

```
sec(t) = 1 + t²/2 + 5t⁴/15 + ...
tan(t) = x + t³/3 + 2t⁵/15 + ...
```

So we might be able to get away with just the first two terms for each dimension in which case we can use a cubic Bezier (as the highest order is t³):

[image: Second/Third order Taylor approximation of the hyperbola]

Turns out, that won't do: It's just way too inaccurate, so we're going to have to better approximate: we create a Bezier curve with start and end points "well off into the distance", with the control points set [such that the Bezier midpoint coincides with the hyperbola's extrema](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#pointcurves). If we try this, we might be fooled into thinking that'll work:

[image: midpoint-aligned Bezier approximation over a small interval]

But if we pick `x` far enough away, we see this approximation quickly stops working:

```
function touchingParabolicHyperbola(a, b, inf=1000) {
  const beziers = [],
        a2 = a**2,
        b2 = b**2;

  let x, x2, y, A, CA;

  for(x=50; x<inf; x+=50) {
    x2 = x**2;
    y = sqrt(b2*x2/a2 - b2);

    // Hit up https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#abc
    // and model the hyperbola in the cubic graphic to
    // understand why the next, very simple-looking,
    // line actually works:
    A = a - (x-a)/3;

    // We want the control points for this A to lie on
    // the asymptote, but for small x we want it to be 0,
    // otherwise the curve won't run parallel to the
    // hyperbola at the start and end points.
    CA = lerp(0, A*b/a, x/inf);

    beziers.push([
      {x,    y: -y}, 
      {x: A, y:-CA}, 
      {x: A, y: CA}, 
      {x,    y}, 
    ]);
  }

  return beziers;
}
```

This shows us a sequence of curves that starts off looking decent but becomes completely useless pretty fast:

[image: midpoint-aligned Bezier approximation over a large interval]

One obvious problem is that the curves end up going past the asymptotes. We can fix that by forcing the control points to (0,0) so that the Bezier hull is a triangle and the curve will always lie inside of that.

```
function tangentialParabolicHyperbola(a, b, inf=1000) {
  const beziers = [],
        a2 = a**2,
        b2 = b**2;

  let x, x2, y;

  for(x=50; x<inf; x+=50) {
    x2 = x**2;
    y = sqrt(b2*x2/a2 - b2);  
    beziers.push([
      {x, y:-y}, 
      {x: 0, y:0}, 
      {x: 0, y:0}, 
      {x, y}, 
    ]);
  }

  return beziers;
}
```

This leads to a series of curves that go from useless on one side, to useless on the other side:

[image: tangent-aligned Bezier approximations]

So single curve approximations are not all that great. What if we use more curves?

#### 3: Poly-Bezier using a Catmull-Rom spline

We can overcome the above problem by using multiple Bezier curves along the hyperbola, which we can (almost trivially) compute by picking a few coordinates on the hyperbola, and then constructing a [Catmull-Rom spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline) through those points. Since a Catmull-Rom spline through N points is equivalent to a poly-Bezier made up of N-3 segments, this could be the winning strategy.

```
function hyperbolaToPolyBezier(a, b, inf=1000) {
  const points = [],
        a2 = a**2,
        b2 = b**2,
        step = inf/10;

  let x, y, x2,
   
  for (x=a+inf; x>a; x-=step) {
    x2 = x**2;
    y = -Math.sqrt(b2*x2/a2 - b2);
    points.push({x, y});
  }

  for (x=a; x<a+inf; x+=step) {
    x2 = x**2;
    y = Math.sqrt(b2*x2/a2 - b2);
    points.push({x, y});
  }

  return crToBezier(points);
}
```

With [the conversion function](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#catmullconv) being:

```
function crToBezier(points) {
  const beziers = [];

  for(let i=0; i<points.length-3; i++) {
    //  NOTE THE i++ HERE! We're performing a sliding window conversion.
    let [p1, p2, p3, p4] = points.slice(i);
    beziers.push({
      start: p2,
      end: p3,
      c1: { x: p2.x + (p3.x-p1.x)/6, y: p2.y + (p3.y-p1.y)/6 },
      c2: { x: p3.x - (p4.x-p2.x)/6, y: p3.y - (p4.y-p2.y)/6 }
    })
  }

  return beziers;
}
```

Let's plot that:

[image: catmull-Rom approximation]

We have to do a bit more work up front compared to flattening, but the upside is that we now have a curve that actually "looks like a curve" at any scale.

#### 4: Combining (1) and (2)

Now, most of the hyperbola actually "looks straight", so using lots of Bezier curves for those parts does feel a bit silly: why not only model the curvy bit with a curve, and model the straight bits with straight lines?

We already saw that if we fix the control point to (0,0), there might be a curve that's at least decent enough, so let's combine approaches 1 and 2, where we can create a single Bezier curve with start and end points "close enough" to the curve, and tacking two line segments onto the ends that join up the bezier curves to two distant points on the asymptotes (which are at `y=±b/a * x`, so any large value for `x` will yield a usable-enough `y`)

Of course the trick is to *find* the distance at which the single curve still captures the curvature, while also making our lines to infinity look like they smoothly join up to our single curve. The Bezier [projection identity](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#abc) comes in handy again: we want `A` to be at `(0,0)` and we want the Bezier midpoint to be at `(a,0)`, which means our start and end points should have an `x` coordinate of `4a`:

```
function hyperbolicallyFitParabolica(a, b, inf=1000) {
  const a2 = a**2,
        b2 = b**2,
        x = 4*a,
        x2 = x**2,
        y = sqrt(b2*x2/a2 - b2)
        bezier = [
          {x: x, y:-y}, 
          {x: 0, y: 0}, 
          {x: 0, y: 0}, 
          {x: x, y: y}, 
        ],
        start = { x1:x, y1:-y, x2:inf, y2: -inf * b/a},
        end   = { x1:x, y1: y, x2:inf, y2:  inf * b/a};

  return [start, bezier, end];
}
```

Which gives us the following result (Bezier in blue, line segments in black):

[image: Combining one Bezier and straight lines]

So that's not great, but it's not terrible either. It's certainly good enough if the audience doesn't scrutinize the render, and it's definitely cheap, but we can do quite a bit better with just a little more work, so: let's also look at the best approximation we can probably come up with here:

#### 5: Combining (1) and (3)

If a single Bezier didn't work, and we already saw that using a Catmull-Rom spline instead of a single curve works way better, then we can of course also just combine approaches 1 and 3. We can form a much better fit around the extrema by constructing two Bezier curves rather than one, by generating five points centered on the extrema and converting the resulting Catmull-Rom spline through those points to Bezier form:

```
function probablyTheBestHyperbola(a, b, inf=1000) {
  let curve = [],
      a2 = a**2,
      b2 = b**2,
      x, y, x2,
      cover = 100;

  // generate two points approaching the midpoint
  for (x=a+cover; x>a; x-=cover/2) {
    x2 = x**2;
    y = -Math.sqrt(b2*x2/a2 - b2);
    curve.add(new Vec2(x, y));
  }

  // generate three points departing at the midpoint
  for (x=a; x<=a+cover; x+=cover/2) {
    x2 = x*x;
    y = sqrt(b2*x2/a2 - b2);
    curve.add(new Vec2(x, y));
  }

  const beziers = crToBezier(curve),
        start = {
          x1: points.get(1).x, y1: points.get(1).y,
          x2: inf, y2: -inf * b/a
        },
        end = {
          x1: points.get(3).x, y1: points.get(3).y,
          x2: inf, y2: inf * b/a
        };

  return { start, beziers, end };
}
```

Which gives us the following result (CR in blue, line segments in black):

[image: Combining Catmull-Rom and straight lines]

And that's probably the best we're going to get in a trade-off between "cheap to compute", "easy to scale", and "looks rights".

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing almost the exact same thing except I'm using SVG instead of the canvas.  From what I recall they are similar enough that this is applicable.  Actually this is regarding Bezier curves in general so application shouldn't matter other than paying attention to the sign of a and y (inverted for graphical applications vs pure math).

Note that this is with the hyperbola centered at the **origin** not the focus. I would recommend coding it this way then using a transform to position and rotate it as needed. I did a lot of playing around in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com), the exact graph is [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/f3ylzpsi84) but I won't bet on that working.

I did this two different ways. One using a quadratic curve and one using a cubic curve. Both use b, which is sqrt(c^2-a^2) instead of e, but easy enough to calculate.

### Cubic Curve

I set the cubic curve to fit the hyperbola from 2a to a, which should be enough to cover the part that the curvature is noticeable. Since the apex was at the halfway point this made it easy to set the x values of the control points.  The Y values were a bit tricky but came out rather elegant.

[cubic curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGqxu.png)

The control points are

```
P1 = (2 * a, b * sqrt(3) )
P2 = (2/3 * a, b * (48-26 * sqrt(3) ) / 18
P3 = (2/3 * a, -b * (48-26 * sqrt(3) )/ 18
P4 = (2 *a, -b * sqrt(3) )
```

To me this is the better option.  If you only need half the hyperbola such as going from parking orbit to ejection orbit then you can clip it.

### Quadradic Curve

[quadradic curve img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nsKg.png)

To use a quadratic curve for an ejection orbit, notice that the tangent at departure is vertical and at true anomaly of 90 the y value is the parameter and the flight path angle, which is the tangent, reduces to tan(phi) = e. The control point is then the intersection of the tangents, so:

```
P1 = (a, 0)
P2 = (a,-e(a + c) + p
P3 = (c, p)
```

To me this curve is a little too short. I was trying to add additional points to extend it, but had trouble getting it right

### Other Options

Another option is creating a curve and using transforms to change the size and shape. Apparently any curve can be created from any another by affine transforms. It's also possible to split a curve into two curves and to change the order of the curve.

Comment: "Apparently any curve can be created from any another by affine transforms" is trivially false. Both Beziers and Circular arcs are curves, and no amount of affine transform can turn one into the other. Even if dealing with just Beziers, it's trivially false because affine transforms can't transform two different coordinates to the same value, so we can't transform between two curves {p1,p2,p3,p4} where curve one has four distinct values, and curve two has p2=p3 (which is a pretty common degenerate case).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for the clarification. I prefaced that with 'apparently' because it was something I ran across in researching this without fully understanding it. Also, in re-reading that I used the term 'curve' ambiguously.  Any hyperbola can be represented as an affine transformation of a unit hyperbola (per Wikipedia), so then would it be correct to say any Bezier curve representing a unit hyperbola could be transformed to represent any hyperbola?

Comment: Beziers are invariant under affine transforms (meaning that applying an affine transform to the coordinates and drawing the curve with those transformed coordinates is equivalent to applying that same affine transform to all on-curve points) so yes, if you have a Bezier that approximates (half of) a unit hyperbola, then you can affine transform that _bearing rounding errors in mind_ because any error in the approximation of the unit hyperbola gets (wildly) amplified by scaling.